# Size Output SVG

Tags: ggiraph

I have a problem. When I create an interactive heatmap or line chart, the output graphic does not behave dynamically; the SVG is always set to a fixed size. This problem cannot be solved with opts_sizing(rescale = TRUE, width = 1) either.

```
interactive_heatmap = function(data){
  
  df = data[[1]] # data 
  print(df)
  days =  unique(data[[1]]["Tag"]) # tage 
  sequenz = max(days$Tag) # last day
  s_min = min(days$Tag) # fist day
  color = data[[2]] # cols 
  textcol = "#303665" 
    ddd = data[[1]]["date"][,1][11,] # pick date 
    
    ddd[, "month"] = format(ddd$date, format = "%m") # pick date 
    ddd[, "Year"]  = format(ddd$date, format = "%Y") #pick date 
    
    mon = return_month(ddd$month) # mon 
   
    #heatmap 
    plt <-ggplot(df, aes(x=hours_only , y=Tag, fill=countfactor ))+
      geom_tile_interactive(aes(tooltip = text_new, data_id = text_new), colour = "white")+
      geom_text(aes(label=round(temperature)), size  = 4)+
      scale_fill_manual(values=color, na.value = "grey90")+
      guides(fill=guide_legend(title="T [°C]"))+
      theme_linedraw(base_size=10)+
      labs(x = "Hour", y = "Day", size = 2)+
      ggtitle(paste0("Hourly Temperature in ", mon," ", ddd$Year))+
      theme(legend.position="right", legend.direction="vertical",
            legend.title=element_text(size = 10,colour=textcol),
            legend.margin=margin(grid::unit(0, "cm")),
            legend.text=element_text(colour=textcol, size=9, face="bold"),
            legend.key.height=grid::unit(0.8, "cm"),
            legend.key.width=grid::unit(0.2, "cm"),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, colour=textcol),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size = 10, vjust=0.2, colour=textcol),
            axis.ticks=element_line(size=0.4, colour = textcol),
            axis.title = element_text(size = 12, color = textcol),
            plot.background=element_blank(),
            panel.border=element_blank(),
            plot.margin=margin(0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, "cm"),
            plot.title=element_text(colour=textcol, hjust=0, size=20, face="bold"))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 23, by = 3))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(s_min,sequenz+s_min-1,1))
    
    return(plt)
    
}
```

```
dd = interactive_heatmap(gd)
```

date                temperature testdate         text_new                      hours    hours_only   Tag Index countfactor
                                                                      
1 2022-07-01 00:00:00        13.7 01.07.2022 00:00 01.07.2022 00:00 
 13.7 °C 00:00:00          0     1 NA    13 - 15
2 2022-07-01 01:00:00        13.4 01.07.2022 01:00 01.07.2022 01:00 
 13.4 °C 01:00:00          1     1 NA    13 - 15
3 2022-07-01 02:00:00        13.0 01.07.2022 02:00 01.07.2022 02:00 
 13 °C   02:00:00          2     1 NA    11 - 13
4 2022-07-01 03:00:00        12.4 01.07.2022 03:00 01.07.2022 03:00 
 12.4 °C 03:00:00          3     1 NA    11 - 13
5 2022-07-01 04:00:00        12.0 01.07.2022 04:00 01.07.2022 04:00 
 12 °C   04:00:00          4     1 NA    11 - 13
6 2022-07-01 05:00:00        11.7 01.07.2022 05:00 01.07.2022 05:00 
 11.7 °C 05:00:00          5     1 NA    11 - 13
7 2022-07-01 06:00:00        11.9 01.07.2022 06:00 01.07.2022 06:00 
 11.9 °C 06:00:00          6     1 NA    11 - 13
8 2022-07-01 07:00:00        12.9 01.07.2022 07:00 01.07.2022 07:00 
 12.9 °C 07:00:00          7     1 NA    11 - 13
9 2022-07-01 08:00:00        14.4 01.07.2022 08:00 01.07.2022 08:00 
 14.4 °C 08:00:00          8     1 NA    13 - 15
10 2022-07-01 09:00:00        15.5 01.07.2022 09:00 01.07.2022 09:00 
 15.5 °C 09:00:00          9     1 NA    15 - 17

## ℹ 734 more rows

```
girafe(ggobj = dd, options = list(
  opts_tooltip(css = "background-color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.75); color:white; padding:2px; border-radius:5px; font-size:12px; border:1px solid #303665;", opacity = 1),
  opts_sizing(rescale =TRUE, width = 1)
))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZolJn.jpg)
```